# Read and write to same netcat tcp connection

Tags: bash, pipe, tcp, netcat, fifo

I have this pipeline:

```
  ( tail -f ${named_pipe} | nc localhost ${port} | ql_conditional_release &> "$HOME/debug.log" & disown; ) &> /dev/null
```

so I am reading from the netcat connection.

How can I write to that same connection? It should be two-way.

Basically if a condition is met in the `ql_conditional_release` function, I want to respond/write back to the *same* socket connection. No idea how to do that though.

Comment: Make it echo into `${named_pipe}` ?

Comment: yeah that sounds good to me lol

Comment: I was thinking of a few things, but not sure why I didn't think about that

Comment: add an answer to receive maximum compensation thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the script echo into ${named_pipe}.